# Is this equality holds? $\overline{F^{*2}}(x)=\int_0^x\overline{F}(x-y)dF(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X_1,X_2$ are non-negative i.i.d random variables with CDF F(x).
I have a problem proving that following identity holds.

$$
\frac{\overline{F^{*2}}(x)}{\overline{F}(x)}=1+\int_0^x\frac{\overline{F}(x-y)}{\overline{F}(x)}dF(y),
$$ 
where $\overline{F^{*2}}(x)=1-P(X_1+X_2\leq x)$
I proved the upper equality as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\overline{F^{*2}}(x)}{\overline{F}(x)}&=\frac{1-\int_0^xF(x-y)dF(y)}{\overline{F}(x)}\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac{1+\int_0^x(1-F(x-y)-1)dF(y)}{\overline{F}(x)}\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac{1-F(x)+\int_0^x\overline{F}(x-y)dF(y)}{\overline{F}(x)}\\[1.5ex]
&=1+\int_0^x\frac{\overline{F}(x-y)}{\overline{F}(x)}dFy
\end{align*}

I looks like everything is good, but I am a bit sceptical if
$$
\overline{F^{*2}}(x)=\int_0^x\overline{F}(x-y)dF(y)
$$
is true???

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general.

$$\Pr\left(X_{1}+X_{2}>x\right)=\int\Pr\left(X_{1}+X_{2}>x\mid X_{2}=y\right)dF\left(y\right)=\int\Pr\left(X_{1}>x-y\right)dF\left(y\right)$$

where independence was used. Since the rv's are nonnegative this equals:

$$\int_{0}^{x}\Pr\left(X_{1}>x-y\right)dF\left(y\right)+\int_{x}^{\infty}\Pr\left(X_{1}>x-y\right)dF\left(y\right)=$$$$\int_{0}^{x}\Pr\left(X_{1}>x-y\right)dF\left(y\right)+\int_{x}^{\infty}1dF\left(y\right)=$$$$\int_{0}^{x}\overline{F}\left(x-y\right)dF\left(y\right)+\overline{F}\left(x\right)$$

Comment: How elegant! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. I like helping.